# If I need to send only 1 byte via a socket, can I just use one char?

Tags: java, sockets, utf-8, tcp, byte

I have a client - server program using TCP. Now I want to send different messages of different size. I read that a `char` in Java is 2 bytes. If I am using UTF-8, can I just send a `char` and it will be of size 1 byte?

Also which is better to use: `DataInputStream` and `DataOutputStream` or `BufferedInputStream` and `BufferedOutputStream` ?

Comment: When you want to send a byte, why not use a `byte`?

Comment: re "If I am using UTF-8, can I just send a char and it will be of size 1 byte?"  It depends on what the character is.  One character occupies one to four bytes when encoded as UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual convention in Java is to write bytes using [`OutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html). Neither of the methods here accepts `char`. You would need to convert the character to `byte[]` array e.g.

```
OutputStream out = ...
byte[] bytes = "my string".getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
out.write(bytes);
```

If you plan to use sockets you can check [`Socket.getOutputStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getOutputStream--) method:

> Returns an output stream for this socket.
>
> If this socket has an associated channel then the resulting output stream delegates all of its operations to the channel. If the channel is in non-blocking mode then the output stream's write operations will throw an `IllegalBlockingModeException`.
>
> Closing the returned `OutputStream` will close the associated socket.

Comment: Yeah, I am using a byte[], but I was thinking if there was a way that the client can write like a char or string and that message would be of different fixed sizes. 
(The thing is that it is required that the server echoes back the message, so if I use byte I can't see a specific message shown to client).

Comment: Yes, you can. You just have to know the encoding used so the bytes can be decoded back into a proper `String` when needed

Answer (score 1):

You want to use an `OutputStreamWriter` to wrap your `OutputStream`.  That will let you specify an encoding, and write `char`s instead of `byte`s.  It's the `OutputStreamWriter`'s job to know the encoding, and to convert `char`s to `byte`s appropriately.  If you have specified that your `OutputStreamWriter` uses UTF-8, and you write a character that uses one byte in UTF-8, you can expect just one byte to be written to the stream.

```
try (OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(myOutputStream, "UTF-8")) {
    writer.write('x');
}
```

You can also wrap the `OutputStreamWriter` in a `BufferedWriter`, for increased efficiency.

But doing the encoding yourself using `getBytes` method of the `String` class is just re-inventing the wheel.  Don't do that.

More information about `OutputStreamWriter` [can be found in the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html).

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 encoding uses from 1 to 4 bytes to store characters, so it is not guaranteed that it will be only 1 byte.

If you want to send just one byte, just use a byte primitive type.

Try this code:

```
try (BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())) {
        String myString = "Hello";
        byte arr[] = myString.getBytes("UTF-8");
        out.write(arr);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I am using:  DataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());  
and then  byte arr[] = new byte[n]  where n is the number of bytes i want to send. 
Then  I sent it via   out.write(arr). 
Will it work this way?

Comment: I have updated my answer with the example code. It will work, and you don't need a DataOutputStream since the write method is the OutputStream class. You need to make sure that you do the UTF-8 conversion correctly.